# AttributeError with numpy in IDLE but not in Python Shell

Tags: python, numpy

The following code executed from an IDLE window produces an error shown below.

```
 import numpy as np
 testarray = np.array([1,2,3], int)
```

Here is the error...

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Test\numpy.py", line 1, in <module>
     import numpy as np
   File "C:\Test\numpy.py", line 2, in <module>
     testarray = np.array([1,2,3], int)
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'array'
 >>>
```

If I do the same thing in the Shell, it works just fine...

```
 >>> import numpy as np
 >>> testarray = np.array([1,2,3], int)
 >>> testarray
 array([1, 2, 3])
 >>>
```

This has been holding me up all day... anyone know how fix it? Perhaps I'm doing something wrong.

Note: If I just execute the code above without the testarray, no error gets returned.

Comment: It works for me in both IDLE and Shell - even with testarray. user2357112 post - that would do it too.

Comment: @sihrc -- I am completely stumped with this. I have no idea why it's not working. I did just add how eliminating the `testarray = np.array([1,2,3], int)` did not return an error.

Comment: check for numpy.py in your working directory as user2357112 suggested

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You named a file `numpy.py`. Python sees that in the module search path and thinks it's the implementation of `numpy`. Pick a different name.

Comment: This was exactly it. Thank you! I will accept this when the time limit is up.

Comment: I should have seen this coming from a mile away, it said line 1.