# Numpy Functions Won't Work in IDLE

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to get numpy into the IDLE, but it won't allow it to work at all. My code is this...

```
import numpy as np
print(np.sqrt(4))
```

Whenever I run this, I get an error saying that numpy has no attribute 'sqrt'. I also can't make arrays or use the trigonometric values. When I run the same thing in the command prompt, however, it works. I am running Python 3.7 on a DELL laptop with Windows 10. I downloaded numpy via pip, so I have the most recent version (1.15.0).

How can I get numpy to work in the IDLE?

Comment: Please add `print(np.__file__)` after the import line and tell us the results; probably you're shadowing numpy with a program of your own.

Comment: sounds like you are having this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936016/attributeerror-with-numpy-in-idle-but-not-in-python-shell

Comment: indeed that is what the problem was, sorry for repeating a question